# Adding a web server and web pages to a .NET WinForms application

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, razor

Is there a simple way to use existing .NET features to add an HTTP server to an existing .NET WinForms application that would read pre-defined HTML pages and embed some of the application's data into the HTML, ideally with Razor? This server would be accessed by clients on the local network while the application is running.

For example, imagine some application that collects data from an external device. An HTML page would be created with special markup to display the data. Multiple clients (desktops, smartphones, etc) on the local network could then access this page using a web browser and view the data.

Comment: A web server runs on a web server and is accessed remotely via a browser. A WinForms application runs locally. These are completely incompatible deployment models.

Comment: @JohnWu yet it is possible to add a self-host Web API to a desktop application. Wouldn't this be going down the same road?

Comment: You maybe could, but what would be the purpose and benefit of doing this, compared to simply adding some more forms to your application to display the same thing?

Comment: @ADyson so that other users on the network can see the application's data, or at  least the summary I intend to provide in the HTML page.

Comment: [ASP.NET Core Self-Hosting with a .NET 5 Windows Forms App](https://github.com/tonysneed/Demo.DotNetSelfHost)

Comment: If you want other users to be able to access the server, perhaps you should deploy it as a separate process that runs as a service or IIS application. That way you don't have to be running the application on your desktop for them to access it. Is there a particular reason you wanted to combine them?

Comment: @JohnWu I wanted to combine them since the data is coming from the desktop app and figured it would be easy to provide it to other users as HTML pages directly. The data and web pages only need to be available while the application is running.

Comment: @Jimi thanks for the link, I will investigate further, it looks more like an API approach. Ideally I'd like to have a single HTML file in which I embed some data from my desktop application.

Comment: Other network users generally won't be able to easily access a web app running on a desktop machine. And it requires that desktop and application to be running all the time so that others can access it at their convenience - which you can't guarantee. also are you the only person on the network who runs this application? You say the data comes "from the application"... doesn't it come from a database? Is the data stored locally on the same machine where the application is installed? I think if we know a bit more about the architecture we could be surer about the right solution here.

Comment: @ADyson the application generates statistics. Imagine you are watching a boxing match and you have an application tracking punches thrown and landed. Someone is running this application ring-side. The TV announcers might want to see those stats but they are on the other side of the ring. Everyone is connected to the same network. You give them your IP address and they can open up a web page with the stats from their computer/tablet/phone. No database involved and the data is only accessed during the match, while the application is running.

Comment: So you don't store the generated statistics for later analysis or consumption, or for audit? It's possible your idea would work if only one or two people would be accessing it (so no excessive load on your local machine) and you don't mind opening your firewall. You'd need a way for the web pages, which will be running on the announcers' machines, to get real-time data from the application, so maybe a SignalR hub running alongside your web app so there's a free flow of stats from the app to the pages? Then the application would send data to the hub, which then feeds it to the clients.

Comment: But if you put that on a separate server (even if that's just another laptop next to you on the desk!) then the whole crowd watching the match could view the stats on their phone, or on a big screen, without any scalability issues. Just a thought anyway.

Comment: @ADyson the statistics are not official so they are just for a few users to view which is why I am trying to keep this as simple as possible. The application already generates an XML feed of the data which is used, in big events, by a separate application to display the statistics, but for lower budget events, a web view would suffice and limit the required hardware (there's not that much room for extra machines). I appreciate your suggestions, the web page would be pretty basic to start with and what you are describing would be the next step.

Comment: Could the page simply read the XML feed then, and refresh it every few seconds using AJAX? That would probably work. And there's no reason why you can't self-host a simple MVC or Razor website from your app if you wish. Just to check - is your application built using .NET 5, or the older .NET Framework?

Comment: @ADyson I was leaning towards the "self-host simple Razor website" approach. The application was built in 2003 but targets the older Framework 4.7.2.